# Default Activity not found?

Tags: android

Android Studio does not run my Application saying that:

> "Error running app: Default Activity not found".

I have tried invalidating caches and restarting.

I have added the intent-filter of `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in the activity tag of the activity I want to set as my main activity.

Comment: please add the code so we can see what may be happening

Comment: Add the code of your manifest.xml file, maybe there is the problem

Comment: Best way to create a new Activity is to right click on the root directory and choose "New" -> "Activity -> "Empty Activity". This automatically creates an entry for your activity file in the Manifest.xml file, where all activity declarations must reside if they are to be used.

Comment: Share your manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add your activity to [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and set a default activity using [`intent-filter`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Also make sure your `<activity>` tag is inside `<application>` tag.

Comment: It worked! Somehow, the application tag was missing and an android tag had taken its place in my manifest file. Thanks